# Min/Max function in Subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question related to SQL Subqueries. I have a dataset, which contains 2 columns: tasker_ID and working_hours, the columns looks like below:

```
    Tasker_ID   working_hours
       1              15
       2              17
       4              4
       1              28
       3              0
       2              17 
       4              23
       5              21
       2              19
       7              18
       7              53
       1              29
            ...
```

And I want to find out which tasker has the most/least working hours.(Here we do not count people who has 0 hours totally.)
At first, I used such SQL query to achieve this:

```
create table table1 as 
    select tasker_id, sum(working_hours) as sum_hours
    from test.test
    group by tasker_id
    having sum_hours > 0
    order by sum_hours;

select tasker_id, sum_hours
from table1
where sum_hours = (select min(sum_hours) from table1);
```

These codes were right, and I got what I want, but I want to try the Subqueries to put these two parts of codes together, you know, without building another tables, and use Min() function to get the minimum working hours on the list based on different ID. 
I knew the Min function goes with the group by statement, and I tried this way:

```
select tasker_id, min(sum_hours)
from (select tasker_id, Count(working_hours) as sum_hours
      from test.test 
      group by tasker_ID
      having sum_hours > 0
     ) a;
```

Obviously, it was wrong, it said that aggregated query need group by statement. And if I added "group by tasker_id" in the last of query, it showed all of the IDs, not the only IDS which has the least/most working hours.

So, is there anyone who can help me with this situation?
I knew there may some different ways to achieve this, but I want to use Min/Max function to subqueries.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your first code uses a separate table `table1` is because it is used twice in the second query. If you write it as one query (without your mistakes) you will find that out and get an error:

```
--this is wrong!
select tasker_id, sum_hours
from (select tasker_id, sum(working_hours) as sum_hours
      from test.test 
      group by tasker_ID
      having sum_hours > 0) a
where sum_hours = (select min(sum_hours) from a)
```

You can't use table `a` again this way; it is not available to the subquery.
Of cours you might go for the ugly solution and repeat the query:

```
-- this is ugly and slow
select tasker_id, sum_hours
from (select tasker_id, sum(working_hours) as sum_hours
      from test.test 
      group by tasker_ID
      having sum_hours > 0) a
where sum_hours = (select min(sum_hours) from (select tasker_id, sum(working_hours) as sum_hours
      from test.test 
      group by tasker_ID
      having sum_hours > 0) b)
```

It gets really awkward when you also want to see the tasker with the maximum amount of hours:

```
-- this is uglier and slower
select tasker_id, sum_hours
from (select tasker_id, sum(working_hours) as sum_hours
      from test.test 
      group by tasker_ID
      having sum_hours > 0) a
where sum_hours = (select min(sum_hours) from (select tasker_id, sum(working_hours) as sum_hours
      from test.test 
      group by tasker_ID
      having sum_hours > 0) b)
or sum_hours = (select max(sum_hours) from (select tasker_id, sum(working_hours) as sum_hours
      from test.test 
      group by tasker_ID
      having sum_hours > 0) b)
```

That's why I would recommend your first solution, only with a temporary table. There is no use cluttering your database with tables for the purpose of querying. Also you should be able to use these two SQL statements, separated by semicolon, in one single call to the database.

```
create temporary table tmphourssum REPLACE as 
select tasker_id, sum(working_hours) as sum_hours
from test.test
group by tasker_id
having sum_hours > 0
order by sum_hours;
select tasker_id, sum_hours
from tmphourssum 
where sum_hours = (select min(sum_hours) from tmphourssum)
or sum_hours = (select max(sum_hours) from tmphourssum)
order by 2 desc
```